# Documenting Ruby on Rails models with YARD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rdoc, yard

I'm using YARD for my Ruby on Rails application documentation.
I have simple model that looks like this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# {Patient} is model responsible for storing patient personal informations.
#
# @!attribute id
#   @return [UUID] ID of the {Patient} in UUID format.
#
# @!attribute name
#   @return [String] Name of the {Patient}.
#
# @!attribute gender
#   @return [String] Gender of the {Patient}.
#
# @!attribute date_of_birth
#   @return [Date] Date of birth of the {Patient}.
#
# @!attribute created_at
#   @return [DateTime] Time when {Patient} was created.
#
# @!attribute updated_at
#   @return [DateTime] Time when {Patient} was updated.

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  # == Relationships ========================================================
  belongs_to :organization

  # == Validations ==========================================================
  validates :name,          presence: true
  validates :date_of_birth, presence: true
  validates :gender,        inclusion: { in: Constants::GENDERS }
end
```

How can I document with YARD my Relationships and Validations?
I saw that there is gem https://github.com/theodorton/yard-activerecord but it was not updated for 6 years.

Comment: I would take a look at this documentation and ask if it actually gives any sort of value at all. It doesn't take a rocket scientist do figure out what `paient.date_of_birth` means. Concentrate on documenting the aspects of the code that are actually unclear/suprising instead. Like for example that the id column is a uuid and the buisness logic enforced by your validations.

Comment: May I ask why you are doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[ruby gem annotate](https://rubygems.org/gems/annotate) is a way to auto-document your functions based on your database

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is an old post, but I see some logic behind it. When you are working with developers who are not so experienced so they might not know by heart what methods a `belongs_to` generates, it makes sense to document it. But does not make sense to do it by hand!
Please don't look at the question from your 10-15-20 years of experience.
Also, having that kind of documentation would make the learning curves of the developers much lower.